# Python PHP and Perl being used together?

Tags: php, python, perl

I was reading through Facebook's hiring now job listings and I saw this...

***  Competency in Shell, PHP, Perl or Python. C is a plus**

This sparked a question in my mind, is it possible to use (for example) python and PHP together?

As in... I write a function in PHP to read a MySQL database and cut the data read into raw string form.

I then use python to use this PHP function to perform operations on this data.

The part where I say "use python to use this PHP function" is this possible?

If so, how? (a small code example would be awesome)

Comment: Even if you could, there is no reason why you'd ever want to. None that wouldn't make sane programmers run screaming, anyway. Chances are good that they just need something new done that those sorts of languages are good for, and don't care much about your particular choice. Or else they have some separate projects using each.

Comment: The only reason I though of this is because... e.g. Programmer one is super proficient in python + programmer two is super proficient in PHP... how do they work together? (in an OOP way of course!)

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, the languages mentioned don't usually play well together at the binary level. (what the OP is asking about) However in many environments this is not uncommon. Libraries written in Pascal, C, and Fortran can sometimes be linked together, assuming you use the same calling convention. The JVM and .NET CLR both allow programs in one language to call libraries in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two answers.

The **simple** answer to this question is to use the exec() function in your PHP scripts to execute python scripts.

There is also the complicated answer, to either build, or use a prior attempted PHP [extension PiP](http://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/):

> this extensions allows the Python interpretter to be embedded inside
>   of PHP (think of PHP as the parent language with Python as its child).
>   This allows native Python objects to be instantiated and manipulated
>   from within PHP. There is also initial support for accessing PHP
>   functions and data from within the embedded Python

I'd love to see some examples of it in use.

Comment: I've thought about the point you've raised before, and will continue looking into examples if I happen to come across any. I think the real issue is the difference in code structure, the Python community vs the PHP community. Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 3):

First, Facebook is a large company. They have many different software projects, apart from the site itself, and some of them are probably written in languages different from the company's mainstream.

Second, teaching a good `$lang1` programmer `$lang2`'s syntax takes two weeks, while teaching a bad `$lang2` programmer how to program takes life.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's *possible* to mix all of this stuff together, it makes no sense at all to do it deliberately. My guess is they have the average [Whitman's Sampler](http://www.russellstover.com/jump.jsp?itemType=CATEGORY&itemID=5) of scripts lying around, written by whomever, whenever, and in whatever language they felt like using. It's a bit of a legacy nightmare, but you don't just chop working code. Most shops eventually prune things back to one or two languages and drop the rest.